# Dynamically cretated control derived from UIImageView has missing functions

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, uiimageview

I have a view controller where I try to dynamically create a CanvasView custom class on the main view by a button click.

I can create the CanvasView instance and see it on the view but the functions in that CanvasView class are not triggering at all for that runtime generated instance.

There is a design time created one called canvasView1 on the view and everything works ok with that one.

I am new to IOS so I am probably making a stupid mistake.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var click: UIButton!


    @IBAction func clicked(_ sender: Any) {
    enter code here
        var  imageView1 : CanvasView!
        imageView1 = CanvasView(frame:CGRect(x: 330, y: 330, width: 100, height: 200));
        imageView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(imageView1)
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var canvasView1: CanvasView!
```

And here is my CanvasView class which derives from UIImageView

```
import UIKit

let π = Double.pi

        class CanvasView: UIImageView {


            // Parameters
          private let defaultLineWidth:CGFloat = 3

          private var drawColor: UIColor = UIColor.red


            override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
                guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0.0)
                let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

                // Draw previous image into context
                image?.draw(in: bounds)

                drawStroke(context: context, touch: touch)

                // Update image
                image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            }
     private func drawStroke(context: CGContext?, touch: UITouch) {
        let previousLocation = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        // Calculate line width for drawing stroke
        let lineWidth = lineWidthForDrawing(context: context, touch: touch)

        // Set color
        drawColor.setStroke()

        // Configure line
        context!.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
        context!.setLineCap(.round)


        // Set up the points
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x:previousLocation.x, y:previousLocation.y))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:location.x, y:location.y))
        // Draw the stroke
        context!.strokePath()

      }

      private func lineWidthForDrawing(context: CGContext?, touch: UITouch) -> CGFloat {

        let lineWidth = defaultLineWidth

        return lineWidth
      }

        func clearCanvas(animated: Bool) {
        if animated {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { finished in
              self.alpha = 1
              self.image = nil
          })
        } else {
          image = nil
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you set `imageView1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`?

Comment: Yep by default a UIImageView (or a subclass) doesn't have the isUserInteractionEnabled property set to true so it ignores touches.  You should check the properties on the one you created in the Interface Builder (I assume that's what design time means)

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but why is the `context` parameter of your `drawStroke` method declared as optional? And then why do you force-unwrap it over and over?

Comment: Well, this is not my code. I found it from raywenderlich website.

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments:

```
  imageView1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

fixed the problem.
Thanks.